# Can't get a value from an object while iterating through an arrayList using a method

Tags: java, object, methods, arraylist

I'm having trouble getting the an element in authors arrayList 'name' value.
Name is a private variable, and must be, so I'm using a method (which I've tested) to return it.
Been programming for just a few weeks, sorry if I'm using incorrect/confusing terminology.

Author is a class
authors is an arrayList of Author objects.

Here is one was I've attempted:

```
//Iterating through all elements of authors
for (i = 0; i < Author.authors.size(); i++)
    Author authTemp = (Author.authors.get(i)); // *****
    String nameTemp = authTemp.getName();// *****
    if (equalsIgnoreCase(nameTemp, entered)){
        nameExists = true;
    break;
}
```

---

And another

```
//Iterating through all elements of authors
for (i = 0; i < Author.authors.size(); i++)
    if (equalsIgnoreCase(**(Author.authors.get(i).getName()**), entered)){
        nameExists = true;
    break;
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problems are you having? What errors are you seeing? And why does Author have its own static ArrayList of itself?

Comment: Your loops don't have braces. This is important.

Comment: The method equalsIgnoreCase(String,String) is undefined for the type book.

Answer (score 0):

You have one arraylist of authors inside author and it can cause infinite recursion, because author1 have a list of authors with author2, and author2 have another list and so on (it may depende on how you have done it).

Try to take the authors arraylist out of author class and check the code braces.

Comment: The authors ArrayList looks to be a static field of the Author class, and so I'm not clear how this will cause infinite recursion. I agree that it does not belong within the Author class, but for design reasons, not for infinite recursion issues -- something the original poster hasn't mentioned as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'm not so sure. And the authors list shoudn't be on author class anyway.

Comment: `"And the authors list shoudn't be on author class anyway."` .... as I've already mentioned.

Comment: Yes. It makes more sense to save the authors list in the "product". For example book have this authors and put there the list.

Comment: I understand it it would probably be better putting it in a different class, which I have now done. The ArrayList is a static, even so I took it out and put it into a new class "Store".

Answer (score 0):

You should make `new` instance of an object to access its methods.

Probably you have something like this:

```
Object obj;
```

This tells the compiler the type of obj but it still empty (null).

And it should be like this:

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

This create a new instance and let you access methods from Object.